# Dynamically starting and stopping timing events

Tags: jquery, setinterval, jquery-events

The **div** Below is being appended to a jQuery popup dialog and it is removed when the dialog is closed.

The idea behind is to make it possible to toggle auto refresh charting data with the click of a button.

```
$('<div/>', {
    style: "position:absolute; top:39px; left:34px;z-index:1",
    click: function(){
        var imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr('src');
        if(imgSrc=="images/green-circle.png"){
            imgSrc="images/black-circle.png";
            //how to stop calling the refresh function?  <--------------
        }
        else{
            imgSrc="images/green-circle.png";
            //Call refresh function every 60 sec
        }
        $(this).find("img").attr('src', imgSrc);
    }
    }).prepend('<img id="theImg"  width="20" height="20" src="images/black-circle-md.png" />').prependTo($(divHolder).parent());
```

Here is an example how to start and stop a timer:

```
var timer;

function startTimer() { 
    timer=setInterval(function(){refreshData()},1000);  
}

function stopTimer() { 
    learInterval(timer); 
}

refreshData(){
    // do some work here
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Question is, how to keep the reference to a `timer` var between the clicks inside the `click: function(){}` function? Because there can be more than one popup dialog active. Refreshing of data should be possible to do independently for different popup dialogs.

Comment: Did you mean `clearInterval` in `stopTimer()`?

Comment: Just thinking aloud: you could have one single timer alway running until there's at least one popup and keep a flag for each popup. All those flags increase:
var popups = [{
   currentTime : 0, //fill increse over time
   isRunning: false //set to true if it has to count
}]

Comment: Either I'm missing something, or all you have to do is replace your comments with function calls for the functions you've already written.

Comment: The clearInterval inside the `<div/> click function` **works**:`(this.refreshTimer); this.refreshTimer = null;` But the timer continues to run if the popup dialog is closed. Unfortunately the code **inside** the `close function` for the **popup dialog** has **no effect in stopping the timer**. `close: function() { var timerDiv = $(divHolder).parent().find("div").first(); clearInterval(timerDiv.refreshTimer); timerDiv.refreshTimer=null; $( divHolder ).remove(); }` How to change this code to make sure that the timer stops when the popup dialog is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your event handler function you have a reference to the particular element that was clicked on in `this`, so you should be able to store the reference to the timer as a property of that element:

```
$('<div/>', {
    style: "position:absolute; top:39px; left:34px;z-index:1",
    click: function(){
        var imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr('src');
        if(imgSrc=="images/green-circle.png"){
            imgSrc="images/black-circle.png";
            clearInterval(this.refreshTimer);
            this.refreshTimer = null;
        }
        else{
            imgSrc="images/green-circle.png";
            this.refreshTimer = setInterval((function() {
                 refreshData(this); // your refreshData function probably needs to know which div to refresh
            }).bind(this), 60000);
        }
        $(this).find("img").attr('src', imgSrc);
    }
})
```

Comment: There is one problem with this solution, the timer event will not stop if the popup dialog is closed. Any ideas how to stop the timer when the dialog is closed?   Code for creating the popup dialog: `$(divHolder).dialog({
  height:'500', 
  width:'840',
  dialogClass:'transparent',
  draggable: false,
  close: function() {
   $( divHolder ).remove();
  }
 }).parent().draggable();`

Comment: @user955732 Is `divHolder` in that code the same as the `<div>` element created in the other jQuery code you posted?

Comment: No, the **divHolder** is actually the popup dialog it self: `$(divHolder).dialog({..});`

Comment: @user955732 Ok, so the `<div>` that has the timer is inside `divHolder`? In that case you just need a way to reference that `<div>` starting from `divHolder`, then call `clearInterval` on its refreshTimer property, inside the close function. Probably something like: `clearInterval($(divHolder).parent().children().get(0).refreshTimer)` The important part is `get(0)` which returns the actual DOM node (which has the refreshTimer property), rather than a jQuery object containing it (which doesn't have that property).